# How to specify a multiline description in upload_video.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmd, youtube-api

I would like to have line break an argument so that the results also have a line break and not just the script.

Current code: `python upload_video.py description="this is a description \ 
second line"`

Results: `this is a description \ second line`

and it should be :

`this is a description
second line`

Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I tried it and everything is being interpreted as literal. Results : this is a description \n second line

Comment: I'm running this on command line, is that the problem?

Comment: and I'm not printing it, I'm just providing it to a python script called upload_video.py

Comment: added the command line picture.

Comment: I added the `youtube-api` tag and made the title of your question more descriptive. I suspect that others have wondered the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution, I'm preparing a post atm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not find a way of making command prompt or console interpret \n as being a new line, so what I did was make the python script replace all `\\` characters with `\n` which will create a new line, since it is been done inside the python script and not outside where it would be interpreted as literal.

New command:

`python upload_video.py --file="video.mp4" --title="test" --description="this is a description\\second line" --category="20" --privacyStatus="private`"

[image]

Now inside the python script. Find `def initialize_upload(youtube, options):` or any function which uploads the video metadata, since it would have the body which has the `snippets`.

add this, it will replace values of `--description=""` which contain `\\` with a new line.

```
#Edit description
editedDescription = options.description
if options.description:
  editedDescription = editedDescription.replace("\\", "\n")
```

now we just need to replace the description value on the `snippets` with the new one.

```
 body=dict(

  #Snippet
  snippet=dict(
   title=options.title,
   description=editedDescription,
   tags=tags,
   categoryId=options.category,

 ),
),
```

Finished code

[image]

Comment: Nice solution -- it is always fun when you can solve your own problem. Ordinarily that would be a good reason to delete a question, but this might be helpful for others.